# ASP MVC 5 - Loading Partials from Root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to make a project where I load some specific Views as Partials from my root directory of the project.

My project structure is something like this:

```
Project
-Controller
-Model
-Views
-DataWrappers
--MyView.cshtml
```

This is like a normal template for any ASP.NET MVC 5 project except DataWrapper's folder. What I want is to load MyView.cshtml as a partial view in a main View. I tried to call it with absolute path using '~/DataWrappers/MyView.cshtml' and passed a custom model in it but it gave me this error:

**The name '@model' does not exist in the current context**

How do I fix this error? I read other articles and they say you need to replace webconfig. Everything is fine here, all other partial views are working fine from Views/Shared directory but this.

Any explanations or help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I loaded my partial view like normally we do.

@Html.Partial("~/DataWrappers/MyView.cshtml", model);

Partial page is like this:

```
@model List<dynamic>


<div class="widget links">
    <ul class="bullet">
        @foreach (var data in Model)
        {

        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Error was on the first line.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your code, just post your actual code. It will make it much easier to find the problem

Comment: Please give your cshtml view and controller action code

Comment: @Andrei I loaded partial like normally anyone would do: @Html.Partial("~/DataWrappers/MyView.cshtml", model)

Comment: @Div folder is in root not in Views folder otherwise it would have worked.